# I need to automate the task of formatting and mounting an SSD when Ubuntu 20.04 LTS starts up

Tags: bash, mount

I am using a local SSD in Google Cloud Platform, and the characteristic of the local SSD provided by Google is that the user has to re-format and mount it every time the user restarts the OS :
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-local-ssd#formatmultiple

I wanted to automate this because it's annoying having to do this manually every time the system restarts. So I created a script in /etc/init.d/automountssd.sh

```
#!bin/bash
sudo mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=4 /dev/nvme0n1 /dev/nvme0n2 /dev/nvme0n3 /dev/nvme0n4
sudo mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/md0
sudo mount /dev/md0 /root/Downloads/
```

Then assign permissions : `chmod 775 /etc/init.d/automountssd.sh`

And I registered it as autorun : `update-rc.d automountssd.sh defaults`

And after rebooting, nothing happened. :(

**Solved : I followed alfajorcito's answer and this works perfectly on GCP platform.**

First I followed his advice and changed #!bin/bash to #!/bin/bash.
And register it as a service by doing the following : `nano /etc/systemd/system/automountssd.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=automount for GCP local ssd

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/automountssd.sh
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And Start the service automatically when booting, and run the service : `sudo systemctl enable automountssd && sudo systemctl start automountssd`

Now whenever the OS is booted, the SSD will be automatically formatted, Raid configured and mounted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shebang is missing a leading slash (i.e. it should be #!/bin/bash not #!bin/bash) - but apart from that, something else is off (unsure what exactly though) - I tried reproducing this with a simple shell script containing a single echo command, but it still didn't work...

However, I did manage to have the script automatically executed after reboot using systemd units, so perhaps you could try doing something similar?
I don't have a GCP account, so I can't guarantee this would solve your local SSD problem, but the following worked on Ubuntu 20 on OCI:

```
# Linux version check
ubuntu@e2-micro-2:~$ uname -a
Linux e2-micro-2 5.11.0-1028-oracle #31~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 26 14:17:34 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# script contents
ubuntu@e2-micro-2:~$ cat /etc/init.d/check-if-this-works.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo 'check' >> /tmp/checkme

# script permissions
ubuntu@e2-micro-2:~$ ls -l /etc/init.d/check-if-this-works.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 41 Feb 19 08:26 /etc/init.d/check-if-this-works.sh

# systemd unit contents
ubuntu@e2-micro-2:~$ cat  /etc/systemd/system/checkme.service
[Unit]
Description=Check me

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/check-if-this-works.sh
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# confirm that output file is missing before reboot
ubuntu@e2-micro-2:~$ ls -l /tmp/checkme
ls: cannot access '/tmp/checkme': No such file or directory

# reload systemd daemon and enable service
ubuntu@e2-micro-2:~$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
ubuntu@e2-micro-2:~$ sudo systemctl enable checkme

# reboot and check if script was successfully executed on startup
ubuntu@e2-micro-2:~$ sudo reboot
(ssh back to server)
ubuntu@e2-micro-2:~$ cat /tmp/checkme
check
```

Comment: Fantastic! working! As you said, I registered automountssd.sh as a service, and now the SSD is automatically formatted, raided and mounted at boot time. Thank you very much! XD